# Tangent lines of a unit disk to a point

Tags: calculus, geometry

Let's say I have a unit disk centered around at a point $(x, y)$ and some other unit disk centered around $(x', y')$ such that their disks do not intersect. What is the best way to find the tangent lines of $(x', y')$'s unit disk that go through $(x, y)$ as a point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change a bit your notation. Let $C_1=(x_1,y_1)$ the center of the first disk and $C_2=(x_2,y_2)$ the center of the second disk. Than the equation of the second disk is $(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=1$. The straight lines from $C_1$ are $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ and the tangents to the second circle are the lines with a slope $m$ such that the system:
$$ \begin{cases}
(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2=1\\
y-y_1=m(x-x_1)
\end{cases}
$$
has only one solution. So, substitute $y$ from the second to the first equation and find the discriminant $\Delta$ of the second equation in $x$ that you find. The equation $\Delta=0$ gives the condition of tangency (only one solution) and it's a second degree equation in $m$. Find the solutions (two solutions if $C_1$ is external to the second circle) and you have the two tangents.

Comment: I feel like I may be doing something wrong, but using the quadratic formula, I'm getting imaginary values for large differences in $x my x_1$... I have 
$$0= \underbrace{(x-x_1)^2}_{a}m^2 + \underbrace{2(x-x_1)(y_1-y_2)}_{b}m + \underbrace{(x-x_2)^2 + (y_1-y_2)^2 - 1}_{c}$$
which leads me to 
$$ m = \frac{-(y_1-y_2) \pm \sqrt{1 -(x-x_2)^2 }}{(x-x_1)}$$

Comment: The equation $\Delta=0$ has two distinct real solutions $m_1$ and $m_2$ if the point $C_1$ is external to the second circle, has coincident solutions $m_1=m_2$ if $C_1$ is on the circle and has no real solution ( complex solutions) if $C_1$ is internal. Test what is the situation and if you have some mistake in the calculations.

Comment: The equation in your comment is not $\Delta=0$. You have to order this equation with respect to $x$ than find the discriminant $\Delta$ that is a second degree polynomial in $m$ that does not contain $x$ but only $the coordinates of  $C_1$ and $C_2$.

Comment: So are you saying I need to solve the quadratic formula for $x$ first and then solve a quadratic formula for $m$ by plugging what we solved from $x$? Would that generate 4 answers? or will you find repeated answers?

Comment: No. Write the quadratic in $x$ that has the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$ where $a,b,c$ are function of $m$. Now write the discriminant of this equation $\Delta=b^2-4ac$ that **must** be a polynomial of degree $2$ in $M$ ( if it is not of second degree there is some mistake in the calculations). Solve the equation $\Delta=0$ and find $m$.